# Calculating place in a contest script

Tags: php, mysql

I was suggested to ask this question again but with more depth.

Here is my script:

```
    <?php
    //Loggedin
    if($_SESSION['login']!=1)
    {
        print "You must be logged in.";
        include($root . 'footer.php');
        exit;
    }
    //Check banned account
    elseif($ui['level']=="2"){
        print "Sorry but your account is banned.";
        include($root . 'footer.php');
        exit;
    }
    //Check email verified
    elseif($ui['email_check']=="0"){
        print "Sorry but your account has not been verified, to verify your account now please visit <a href='index.php?index=verify&email=".$ui['email']."'>THIS LINK</a>.";
        include($root . 'footer.php');
        exit;
    }
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$country= $ui['country'];
$dates=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `contest` WHERE `countries` LIKE '%$country%'");
$timestamp = time();

    $getcontests = $os_DB->query("SELECT * FROM contest WHERE date_1 <= '$timestamp' AND date_2 >= '$timestamp' AND countries LIKE '%$country%'");
        $num = $os_DB->num($getcontests);

            if($num == 0){
            print"<td colspan='4'>There are currently no active contests</td>";
            }
            else
            {

    while ($dat = mysql_fetch_array($dates)) {
        $tname = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $dat['name']);
        $places="(SELECT * FROM `".$tname."_contest` WHERE `username` <> 'cassa' ORDER BY `completed` DESC LIMIT ".$dat['rewards'].")";
        $results=mysql_query($places) or die(mysql_error());




        $reward = array("".$dat['reward_1'].",".$dat['reward_2'].",".$dat['reward_3'].",".$dat['reward_4'].",".$dat['reward_5'].",".$dat['reward_6'].",".$dat['reward_7'].",".$dat['reward_8'].",".$dat['reward_9'].",".$dat['reward_10']."");

        $rewards = implode(",", $reward);

        $rewardsa = explode(",", $rewards);
        $i=0;
        $a=1;

            // Offers Contest

        if(time() <= $dat['date_2'] && time() >= $dat['date_1'] && $dat['type'] == offer) {
            print" <table width ='100%'><tr><th align='center'><font size='4'>{$dat['name']}</font></th><th align='right'><font size='1'>".date("m/d/Y h:i A", $dat['date_1'])."-".date("m/d/Y h:i A", $dat['date_2'])."</font></th></tr></table><br />".$dat['desc']."<br /><font size='1' color='white'>You must complete offers worth at least ".$dat['min_points']." points or $".$dat['min_cash']." to count towards contest!<br /><br />
            You must also complete at least ".$dat['min_offers']." offers in order to be eligible for winnings.</font><br /><br />";
            print" <table width ='100%'><tr><th align='left'>Place</th><th align='center'>User</th><th align='right'>Prize</th><th align='right'>Completed</th></tr>";

        if(mysql_num_rows($results) == 0){
            foreach($rewardsa as $rewa){
                if(!empty($rewa['$i'])){
                    if($dat['r_type'] == points){
                        print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$a}</td><td align='center'>......</td><td align='right'>{$rewardsa[$i]} points</td><td align='right'>--</td></tr>";
                    }
                if($dat['r_type'] == cash){
                    print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$a}</td><td align='center'>......</td><td align='right'>$".$rewardsa[$i]."</td><td align='right'>--</td></tr>";
                }
            $i++;
            $a++;
                }
            }
        }


    while ($place = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        if($dat['r_type'] == points){
            print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$a}</td><td align='center'>{$place['username']}</td><td align='right'>{$rewardsa[$i]} points</td><td align='right'>{$place['completed']}</td></tr>";
        }
        if($dat['r_type'] == cash){
            print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$a}</td><td align='center'>{$place['username']}</td><td align='right'>$".$rewardsa[$i]."</td><td align='right'>{$place['completed']}</td></tr>";
        }
        $i++;
        $a++;

    }
    ///Line I am working with///
    $getyou= mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Place, t.*
    FROM ".$tname."_contest t
    GROUP BY t.id
    HAVING Place <= 3 OR username = '".$ui['username']."'");
        $youu = mysql_fetch_array($getyou);
        print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$youu['Place']}</td><td align='center'>You</td><td align='right'>---</td><td align='right'>{$youu['completed']}</td></tr>";
        }
    }
        }

?>  
        </table>
```

With this script I want to be able to show the logged user the place that they currently stand in the contest under the current winners.

This is what I want the table to look like.

```
-----------------------------------------
| Place |    User   | Prize | Completed |
|   1   | Someuser1 | $5.00 |     5     |
|   2   | Someuser2 | $2.50 |     3     |
|   3   | Someuser3 | $1.25 |     2     |
|   20  |    You    |  ---  |     1     |
-----------------------------------------
```

This is how it looks

```
-----------------------------------------
| Place |    User   | Prize | Completed |
|   1   | Someuser1 | $5.00 |     5     |
|   2   | Someuser2 | $2.50 |     3     |
|   3   | Someuser3 | $1.25 |     2     |
|   1   |    You    |  ---  |     1     |
-----------------------------------------
```

here is my table structure.

```
    Column   |  Type | Null |  Default
--------------------------------------
    id       |int(11)|  No  |   
    username |text   |  No  |   
    completed|int(11)|  No  |
```

As you can see it is all coming from one table and the place isn't defined by the database, but by the script itself.

Hopefully this can clarify more than my last question.

Edit: With Sean's code this is what I get.

```
-----------------------------------------
| Place |    User    | Prize | Completed |
|   1   |   kikkat   | $5.00 |     1     |
|   2   |xXchris744Xx| $2.50 |     1     |
|   3   |  kira423   | $1.25 |     1     | /// This line is me
|   7   |    You     |  ---  |     1     | /// But it shows my current place as 7
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @PeeHaa I know how to use mysqli and prepared statements, but this is a prebuilt script, I was asked to edit it, that is all.

Comment: In that case at least indent your code so you (and others) can see what is happening.

Comment: @PeeHaa thanks for the suggestion, my auto indent wasn't activated in notepad++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a nested query -

```
$getyou= mysql_query("SELECT 
                        (SELECT count(*)+1 AS rank FROM contest WHERE completed >
                          (SELECT completed FROM contest WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."' ORDER BY completed DESC LIMIT 1)) as Place,
                        c.* FROM contest c WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."'");
$youu = mysql_fetch_array($getyou);
    print"  <tr><td align='left'>{$youu['Place']}</td><td align='center'>You</td><td align='right'>---</td><td align='right'>{$youu['completed']}</td></tr>";
```

---

Here is how the query works from the inside out-

The 1st (inside) `SELECT` gets the `completed` amount for the `username =$ui['username']`

```
SELECT completed FROM contest WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."' ORDER BY completed DESC LIMIT 1
```

The 2nd (middle) `SELECT` uses that `completed` amount and does a `count` of all the rows that have more completed, adds a `1` to that `count`, and saves it as the users `Place`.

```
SELECT count(*)+1 AS rank FROM contest WHERE completed > '#' // # represents the `completed` amount for the `$ui['username']` that we got in the 1st SELECT
```

The 3rd/Last (outside) `SELECT` now just gets the row data for `username =$ui['username']`

```
SELECT Place, c.* FROM contest c WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."'  // Place was created/defined in early SELECTS, now we just get the rest of the data using c.*
```

---

Edit

To add a `tiebreaker` when one or more have the same number `completed`, you need to order your query by the `id` as well. So change your first query to -

```
$places="(SELECT * FROM `".$tname."_contest` WHERE `username` <> 'cassa' ORDER BY `completed`,`id` DESC LIMIT ".$dat['rewards'].")";
                                                                                              ---
```

And add `ORDER BY id` and `>=` to the 2nd query

```
$getyou= mysql_query("SELECT 
                        (SELECT count(*)+1 AS rank FROM contest WHERE completed >=
                                                                                --
                          (SELECT completed FROM contest WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."' ORDER BY completed DESC LIMIT 1) ORDER BY `completed`,`id`) as Place,
                                                                                                                                 -------------------------
                        c.* FROM contest c WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."'");
```

---

Edit #2
Try this new query. The previous one was not selecting the exact row, but the last of the `tied`.

```
$getyou= mysql_query("SELECT Place, c.* FROM
                      (SELECT @Place:=@Place+1 AS Place, c.*
                        FROM contest c, (SELECT @Place := 0) r ORDER BY completed DESC, id ASC ) c
                         WHERE username = '".$ui['username']."'");
```

This new query creates a temporary new column `Place`, using `SELECT @Place := 0`, and then we get the users 'Place' using `@Place:=@Place+1 AS Place`.

Comment: it does work, but there is just one issue I can't seem to figure out. If there are a bunch of member that have completed the same amount, for example a users in place 2 and 3 have only completed 1 and then say the current user has completed 1 it would show that they are in 2nd place as well. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: What is your `tiebreaker` conditions? In your example how do you determine who gets `2nd` & `3rd`? Do you offer multiple `2nd`'s and 0 `3rd`'s, or is there a `tiebreaker` based off `id`, so if they entered earlier than the others with the same number of `completed` they get the `prize`. When doing contests/prizes you need clear, defined guidelines, including `tiebreaker` conditions.

Comment: It pulls the first 2 by id, so if they entered earlier they would get the prize, but it does this automatically its not really defined in the script.

Comment: In order to do the `tiebreaker` conditions by `id`, you need to add that to your query. I have edited my answer to show how it can be done.

Comment: I found that my original query was selecting the last row, when there was a tie, not the row of the user. I have edited again with a new query. This one creates a temporary column `Place`, and get the users 'Place'.